# Why are my Nautilus scripts listed in reverse order?

Tags: scripts, nautilus

I've recently upgraded to GNOME 3.22. My Nautilus scripts are now listed in reverse alphabetical order in the Scripts sub-menu. In the Nautilus folder view, files in the Scripts folder and all other folders use the default order -- alphabetical by name. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried changing the sort order? It may be specified per-folder.

Comment: When I navigate to the Scripts folder in Nautilus "/$HOME/.local/share/nautilus/scripts" the entries are alphabetical by name. When I right-click on a file in Nautilus and select the Scripts sub-menu, the entries are in **reverse** alphabetical order, by name. See screenshot: http://www.greene-family.org/tony/images/Scripts-Folder.jpg